# How to create C++ template class with 2 datatype parameters based on 2 enum values checking?

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I have a template class which contains 2 type parameters. While I create the class instance, I need check 2 other enum value to decide the this class type parameter.

```
enum DataType_t
{
    DATA_TYPE_INT32 = 1,
    DATA_TYPE_FLOAT = 2,
    DATA_TYPE_DOUBLE = 3
    // totally more then 10 type enum value,
};

class MyClassBase
{};


template<typename InputDataType, typename OutputDataType>
class MyClass:public MyClassBase
{
private:
    InputDataType inputData;
    OutputDataType outputData;
public:
    MyClass() {};
    ~MyClass() {};

};

MyClassBase* make_instance(DataType_t inputDataType, DataType_t outputDataType)
{

    switch (inputDataType)
    {
    case DATA_TYPE_INT32:
        switch (outputDataType)
        {
        case DATA_TYPE_INT32:
            return new MyClass<int, int>();
        case DATA_TYPE_FLOAT:
            return new MyClass<int, float>();
        case DATA_TYPE_DOUBLE:
            return new MyClass<int, double>();
        }
        break;
    case DATA_TYPE_FLOAT:
        switch (outputDataType)
        {
        case DATA_TYPE_INT32:
            return new MyClass<float, int>();
        case DATA_TYPE_FLOAT:
            return new MyClass<float, float>();
        case DATA_TYPE_DOUBLE:
            return new MyClass<float, double>();
        }
        break;
    case DATA_TYPE_DOUBLE:
        switch (outputDataType)
        {
        case DATA_TYPE_INT32:
            return new MyClass<double, int>();
        case DATA_TYPE_FLOAT:
            return new MyClass<double, float>();
        case DATA_TYPE_DOUBLE:
            return new MyClass<double, double>();
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

I can write `make_instance` function like above, but I feel it is not an elegant way.  Actually, the enum `DataType_t` define more than 10 data types, If I list them all inside switch case, it will be too complex to maintain.

I wonder whether there is a better approach to handle the scenario? And my project is using C++98, not upgrade to C++11 yet.Thanks.

Regards,
Yanhua

Comment: are `inputDataType` and `outputDataType` known at compile time?

Comment: no, only can be decided in run time by 2 DataType_t parameters.

Comment: @Yanhua, that's very relevant. Perhaps it should be mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This code of yours will force the compiler to implement 100 or more variations of your class, for no gain in performance or readability. This is plain crazy, if you ask me.

One could wonder why you need dynamic instanciation in the first place, but surely you have a pretty good reason...

You could use doubles for your data, of maybe make a specialization for integer values if you require perfect integer precision.

Then you could store the data types, assuming you require some specific processing like displaying the numbers according to the original type, which might not even be necessary.

Forget about C++ magicking your design problems away, that's my advice. This is the kind of language that can produce monstruosities even with careful design, and only more so if you ask it to on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

I didn't know that's for runtime since your comment, so the solution below does not work for you. (But I let it here is case where it inspires you for a different implementation.

You have to know something: **Templates are evaluated a COMPILE time and are therefore not an efficient tool since you are trying to evaluate type at RUNTIME.**

You will need to define every possibilities.

## Deprecated answer

### Solution 1

In *this* case, why don't you just use `using` keyword ?

```
using DATA_TYPE_FLOAT = float;
using DATA_TYPE_INT32 = int;

const auto my_c = MyClass<DATA_TYPE_INT32, DATA_TYPE_FLOAT>();
```

### Solution 2

Change the purpose of your `make_` function. Just like the STL does, you should build your object passing parameters which are going to be hold by your `MyClass`. In your case, you are doing wrong. Here is my solution:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename I, typename O>
class MyClass {

    private:
        I input;
        O output;

    public:

        MyClass(const I& new_input, const O& new_output)
        : input(new_input), output(new_output) {}
};

template <typename I, typename O>
auto make_instance(I input, O output) -> MyClass<typename std::decay<I>::type, typename std::decay<O>::type> {
    return MyClass<typename std::decay<I>::type, typename std::decay<O>::type>(input, output);
}

int main() {
    const auto c = make_instance(4, 3.2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how either of these help with selecting the type depending on *runtime* condition.

Comment: @user2079303: I was writing the code when he posted his comment. I didn't know.